# How to access nested class B in an interface?

Tags: java

```
interface C {
    class B {
        void run() {
            System.out.println("nested class run method");
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

How to access the run method in class B in interface C?

Comment: Why to have that design in the first place?

Comment: I agree, this makes no sense. In general I try to avoid nested static classes (static is implicit here since it is in an interface) since it generally means the containing class is doing too much. I typically try to extract an interface and create a "real" class that operates on that interface. More verbose, but cleaner.

Comment: @JohnGaughan static inner classes can be useful for custom `Comparator` implementations that must be used only within the class.

Comment: @Luiggi I agree, for comparators or file matchers they can be useful. That is why I said I "generally" try to refactor them out, not always. I have seen too many cases where developers tried to put too much code in one class, then realized multiple objects are required (perhaps for multithreading) and hence the static inner class is born... with more code bloat.

Answer (score 3):

You must prefix the name of the class with the name of its enclosing interface:

```
C.B runner = new C.B();
runner.run();
```